# Suggestions for proximity analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

For a GIS assignment I have used raster analysis map overlays in ArcMap to find areas where, if legalised, cannabis dispensaries would be able to be located in London.

I have identified several small areas which are further than 1000ft from schools, nurseries, parks and playgrounds etc.

At present, many of the 'legal' locations seem to be near train stations, notably Paddington, Charing Cross and London Bridge - is there a way of quantifying this relationship?
[image: Map showing 'legal areas' in Central London]

Comment: Perhaps look at proximity analysis using the Near tool.

Comment: Do some googling around site suitability analysis.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/tutorial/exercise-3-finding-a-site-for-a-new-school.htm

Comment: Review our self-assembling FAQ on Proximity: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proximity?sort=frequent

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the train stations are point data, so you are trying to find a relationship between points and polygons.

1. Near tool - works with points, lines, or polygons.  Can compare point/point, point/line, point/polygon, line/line, line/polygon, polygon/polygon.  This tool will add attributes to your feature class.  Here is the documentation, which covers everything you need to use the tool:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm
2. If you do not want to modify your input data, use "Generate Near Table".  This works the same way as the near tool, but creates a stand alone table instead of adding attributes to your input data.  This tool also allows you to calculate distances from more than one feature class (i.e. distance to train stations and distance to atms).  Here is the documentation:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm